# Download Google Trends data with R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I cannot find a similar problem on StackOverflow. I apologize if it is out there...

I have a list of dataframes, all with a date column and a value for each date. I would like to combine this list into one dataframe, with one data column, and the value from each list.

I have this:

```
> list
$IBM
         Date IBM
1  2012-03-01  98
2  2012-03-02  94
3  2012-03-03  49
4  2012-03-04  48

$AAPL
         Date AAPL
1  2012-03-01   43
2  2012-03-02   38
3  2012-03-03   13
4  2012-03-04   10

$HPQ
         Date HPQ
1  2012-03-01  62
2  2012-03-02  67
3  2012-03-03  24
4  2012-03-04  37
```

I would like this:

```
         Date    IBM   AAPL    HPQ
1  2012-03-01     98     43     62
2  2012-03-02     94     38     67
3  2012-03-03     49     13     24
4  2012-03-04     48     10     37
```

Using `do.call("cbind", list)` I get this:

```
> do.call("cbind", test)
IBM.Date IBM.IBM  AAPL.Date AAPL.AAPL   HPQ.Date HPQ.HPQ

1  2012-03-01      98 2012-03-01        43 2012-03-01      62
2  2012-03-02      94 2012-03-02        38 2012-03-02      67
3  2012-03-03      49 2012-03-03        13 2012-03-03      24
4  2012-03-04      48 2012-03-04        10 2012-03-04      37`
```

This is very simliar to what I want, but with multiple repeated date columns.  Is there a way to do this? Preferably in the base package?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You could also use `join_all(lst)` from `library(plyr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list looks like this

```
#sample data
dts<-c("2012-03-01","2012-03-02","2012-03-03","2012-03-04")
dd<-list(
  IBM=data.frame(Date=dts, IBM=c(98,94,49,48)),
  APPL=data.frame(Date=dts, APPL=c(43,38,13,10)),
  HPQ=data.frame(Date=dts, HPQ=c(62,67,24,37))
)
```

Then you can create the output you want with

```
Reduce(merge, dd)
#         Date IBM APPL HPQ
# 1 2012-03-01  98   43  62
# 2 2012-03-02  94   38  67
# 3 2012-03-03  49   13  24
# 4 2012-03-04  48   10  37
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great. Did not know about the reduce function.